# Adding an image in AS3 via external XML

Tags: xml, image, actionscript-3, file, external

I think this is relatively simple, it just does not seem to be working for me. I think I am on the right track. 
This is what I have:

```
import mx.controls.Image;

        public var newImage:Image;

        public var myXML:XML;
        public var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        public function init():void{
            myLoader.load(new URLRequest("images.xml"));
            myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
        }

        public function processXML(e:Event):void{
            myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
            newImage = new Image();
            newImage.source = myXML.IMAGE.@src;
            imgGroup.addElement(newImage);

        }
```

It is not displaying the image for me though. Any ideas?

Here is my XML for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GALLERY COLUMNS="5" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="100">
<IMAGE src="img_data/download.jpg"  />

</GALLERY>
```

Comment: Just for reference in the future, you should access each node of an XML object by using `[INDEX]`, even if there is only one element. So `myXML.IMAGE.@src` should actually be `myXML.IMAGE[0].@src`. It is a bit faster (only noticeable in massive amounts, though) to parse and makes it much more flexible if you do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you need to load your images before you can use them.  You do this with the [Loader class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html), just as you loaded your XML with the [URLLoader class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html).

See [How to Load External Images in Actionscript 3.0](http://blog.728media.com/2009/03/11/how-to-load-external-images-in-actionscript-30/)

Comment: The `Image` class in Flex already loads the image when you set its `source` property.

Comment: I can easily do it within flex, however I am required to load it from XML. Would I do something like this?

imgLoader.load(myLoader);

assuming I did this:
public var imgLoader:Loader;

Comment: While I don't use Flex, I do load images from the path given in XML objects on a daily basis using both URLLoader (for XML) and Loader (for images).  This solution should work if Flex supports AS3 (which it does).  Just check for `image` nodes and use the `src` attribute as the path when calling `Loader`.